# The type ActionBar.Tab is deprecated from api 21 error

Tags: android

I making a tab code , and reusing the same code from past application.

and after updating api 21 the issue coming to this.

The type ActionBar.Tab is deprecated.

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;

what should be solution ?

Comment: i am getting problem , not finding solution still

Comment: is it not working? your question isn't a question, just a statement.

Comment: If Google wants to deprecate it then I can't prevent them to do it!

Comment: The solution of course is not to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what should be solution ?

change it to other tab implementation method like:

1)[FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

2)[TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html)

3)[PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

4)[SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

Comment: FragmentTabHost is nice to use.